# Why are the theoretical and measured frequency responses off a low pass filter different?

Tags: filter, low-pass, frequency-response

The calculated/theoretical value for the cutoff frequency was different to the measured.

What is the reasoning behind this other than measurement errors?

It should be noted that this was a simple RC low pass filter.

Comment: How did you calculate your theoretical value, from an equation or from a graph? Also the calculated value is from an actual component values from a circuit?

Comment: And how did you measure it? Oscilloscopes have a roll off too.

Comment: From an equation; f_cutoff=1/2πRc using component values from the circuit.  The measured valued was from an oscilloscope.

Comment: And what are you comparing it to? Did you measure it with oscilloscope or measure component values then also use the equation?

Comment: How much it was off? How precise components you used?

Comment: It would also help if you told us what results you got and what you expected. It could be non idealities or you just did something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

> *What is the reasoning behind this other than measurement errors?*

- tolerances of components
- wrong theoretical calculation
- incorrect measurement procedures (wrong impedance scope-probe)
- test equipment errors (out of tolerance or calibration)
- human errors (mis-reading numbers / figures)
- implementation error (such as impedance of signal generator)
- implementation error (incorrectly wiring the filter)
- implementation error (someone using the wrong components)
- parasitic components
- skin effect
- loop inductance effects
- mis-reporting of results
- EM interference
- didn't take account of transmission line effects
- someone lying
- someone a bit deaf or can't read the numbers written down
- espionage (deliberate doctoring of the numbers or the test method)
- an extreme case of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle
- red shift
- drugs were involved
- it was all a dream
- theoretical vs measured were slightly different but within sensible expectations

Comment: Oh no drugs and electronics mixed together is never good. Even drinking and electronics don’t mix.

Comment: @Leoman12 one shot of everclear for me, and another shot onto the PCB to clean the flux

Comment: @DKNguyen Just be sure you take that shot of Everclear after you add the shot to the PCB and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you used the ideal values of the components. For example if you used a 10nF capacitor and 10k ohm resistor you used those exact values. And when you measured with your oscilloscope you were using real components. Most likely reason for difference in measured and calculated value for corner frequency is that in real components they aren’t exactly equal to their stated value. They have a tolerance. For example a 10k resistor with 5% tolerance will have a actual value ranging from 9500 ohm to 10500 ohm. Similarly for your capacitor which might be 10nF with 10% tolerance can range in value from 9nF to 11nF. This is why your measured and theoretical values differ. Note I assume that you did a correct measurement setup.

Comment: DC bias on the cap could also easily throw it off by 30% or more.

Answer (score 0):

tolerances of components

source and load impedances

scope tolerances

your eyeball errors in reading the scope

your math errors

Answer (score 0):

Oscilloscopes have a roll off. DC bias on most ceramic caps will reduce the capacitance. Caps and resistors also have parasitics.

We REALLY need way more info on what you did, what you used, and how you did it. For all we know you used a ceramic cap with high DC bias, a wire wound resistor, measured your capacitance at a frequency different than what you were running through it (caps have parasitic inductance) and running a frequency close to the roll off of your scope, and you used 3 instead of Pi in your equations. All that could throw your measurement of by >50%.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a high impedance, high frequency rolloff was calculated but the measured circuit was built on a solderless breadboard that has many stray capacitances between the rows of contacts and the wires all over the place.